# Detecting taps on Custom Cells of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So i have a custom `UITableViewCell` which contains three `UILabel`. The `UITableViewCell` is such that the `UILabel` completely cover the cell.

Now i want to detect whenever user taps on the cell. Problem is as the `UILabel` cover the cell I cannot use `UITableView` delegate method for detecting touch on the cell.

I thoughout about using gesture recoginzers on the `UILabel` but then i don't get the index of the touched cell. I also thought about placing a transparent button on top of the cells but here there is also the same problem that i can't get the index of the touched cell.

Can anybody guide me with an approach on how can i accomplish detecting taps with `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath` when `UILabel` are covering the cell.

Comment: Just disable the user interaction on the labels and then check.

Comment: Ok something weird happen i enabled user interation at all the labels and now the code is working it is calling the delegate methods.

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

Try to set userInteractionEnabled to false in all labels in cell. This will pass touch to the cell and then you can use UITableView delegates. Be sure that cell stays userInteractionEnabled = YES

Comment: Ok something weird happen i enabled user interation at all the labels and now the code is working it is calling the delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

To get the touch event besides `didSelect` method try this. In your custom cell class add a block like,

```
typedef void(^TappedCell)(CustomCell *cell);
```

and add a property for it,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) TappedCell tappedCell;
```

and on transparent button action

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped {

    if (self.tappedCell) {
        self.tappedCell(self);
    }
}
```

And in `cellForRow` method

```
__weak type(self)weakSelf = self;
cell.tappedCell = ^ (CustomCell *tappedCell) {

     //Ur actions goes here
     //for getting index
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [weakSelf.tableView indexPathForCell:tappedCell];
     [weakSelf someActionWithIndexPath:indexPath];
};
```

Comment: what is the advantage of this method over others?

Comment: @Bhavin the OP was asked for an alternate method other than didSelectRow, that why this solution. In your case, you are adding indexpath.row as tag and on button action you are determining row from tag. Keep in mind that using tags for the index path only works if your table rows can't be added, removed, or reordered. It will be also make problems if you have multiple sections too. So keeping custom cell button actions inside the cell and sending a callback to view controller will be the good approach

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt matter whether `UILabel` hide your cell or `UIImageView` hide it. It will automatically detects `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Check it first you wont face any problems. Did you try to implement tableview in detail first