# How to make UIButton stay selected in a tableview when scrolled down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have button in cell.swift file which has a button on it and this is the target function.

If I select the button and scroll down and go back up it get unselected again.

I've tried multiple variations of `setSelected` and set highlighted but nothing is working.

```
func selectRecipient(sender:UIButton) {
    if (!selectToShareButton.selected) {
        selectToShareButton.selected = true
        selectToShareButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkSelected"), forState: .Selected)  
    } else {
        selectToShareButton.selected = false
        selectToShareButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkUnselected"), forState: .Normal)
   }
}
```

Comment: Your are dequeuing the cells and making new one every time you scroll, I don't think you can achieve what you want with that. There is a way around though, you can set certain buttons selected using indexPath.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507770/maintain-state-of-custom-button-in-uitableview-cell-when-scrolls ... it describes some steps may be helpful to you

Answer (score 5):

You should keep the state of your buttons in an array and in datasource function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` read the state and configure your cell button.

Comment: To the point answer +1 for that. But you could elaborate on that for sure.

Comment: Can you write some code for example? how would i edit my function?

Comment: @HaasithSanka I have added an answer to roughly describe how it can be done.

Comment: @HaasithSanka I can write some code but I prefer to do it yourself (to practice) and get back to us here to help you when you struggle.

Answer (score 1):

This is because table view reuses cell and dequeuing it continuously with scroll. So everytime your cell created and destroyed when you scroll so all the property will set to default which you are setting in `cellforrow` or in cell's custom class if it available.

So, you can manage this something like, You can set `tag` to your button as `indexpath.row` and when you select button set some `flag` or save it's tag somewhere and put condition in `cellforrow` that if button's tag is from saved tags than make it selected.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a selectedArray that maintains the button selection track

```
 var selectedButtonsArray = [{
isSelected = true
},
{isSelected = false}
]
```

1. add a object in array when  button selected
2. remove object from array when deselected
3. In cell for row delegate method show button according the array

Hope this may help you,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Hossam's answer,

You can create an array of boolean values that indicate whether a cell is selected or not.

```
var selectedBoolArray = [Bool]()
```

You can add target for you button so that it fires a method everytime this button is tapped:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   /// If your button is referenced from storyboard. Or add target to each button somehow.
    YourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourClass.methodToSelect(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

}


func methodToSelect(sender: UIButton)
{
let index = sender.tag 
selectedBoolArray[index] = true
}
```

then in your cell for cellforrowatindexpath method,  you can set these bools to false or true like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


        if selectedBoolArray[indexPath.row] {
           // set you button  selected, cell.button.selected = true?
        }


    YourButton.tag = self.indexPath.row

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Can the methodtoselect function be in the cell.swift?

Comment: @HaasithSanka is your button an IBOutlet? It can be done certainly. You can add Notification observer

Comment: No it's not its made programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You should manage the model of cell:

```
func BtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var point: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.categoryTable)
    var index: NSIndexPath = self.categoryTable(forRowAtPoint: point)
    var cell: UITableViewCell = self.categoryTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index)
    category.manageCell(index.row)
    self.categoryTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([index], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if category.indexArray.containsObject(Int(indexPath.row)) {
        checkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_check"), forState: .Normal)
    }
    else {
        checkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_uncheck"), forState: .Normal)
    }
    return cell
}

func manageCell(index: Int) {
    // index array mutable array
    if !indexArray.containsObject(Int(index)) {
        indexArray.append(Int(index))
    }
    else {
        indexArray.removeAtIndex(indexArray.indexOf(Int(index)))
```

Comment: answer is requested in swift